# How to join two table to retrieve rows from them and print it in within 1 div?

Tags: php, sql, join, mysqli

I have successfully pulled all required fields from one table ['hotel' is my table name]. 
Also, I want to pull some fields from another table ['rates' is another table name] simultaneously. How can I do it?

Here is my working code for table 'hotel':

```
<!--deal-->
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'swaminarayan');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hotel")) {
$directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{?
<article class="one-fourth">
<figure>
<?php 
$search_dir = "$directory/{$row['name']}{$row['hotel_address']}";
$images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
sort($images);
//display images
//display random image
if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
// Get a random index in the array with rand(min, max) which is inclusive
    $randomImageIndex = rand(0, count($images)-1);
    $img = $images[$randomImageIndex]; // random image
    echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
}else {
// possibly display a placeholder image?
} ?
</figure>
<div class="details">
<h1><?php echo " ".$row['name']." ";?>
</h1>
<span class="price">Price per room per night from  <em>$<?php echo " ".$row['defult_price']." ";?></em> </span> // This defult_price is not from table 'hotel', it is from table 'rates' 
<div class="description">
<p><?php echo " ".$row['hotel_description']." ";?> <a href="<?php echo "".$row['hotel_address']."";?>.php">More info</a></p>
</div>
<a href="booking-step1.php" title="Book now" class="gradient-button">Book now</a>
</div>
</article><?php }}?>
<!--//deal-->
```

In above, I want to pull room rate field from 'rates' table and display here{ as here: `[<span class="price">Price per room per night from  <em>$<?php echo " ".$row['default_price']." ";?></em> </span> }]`, this only value from table 'rates', else all are from table 'hotel'.

Comment: Erm, there is no JOIN part in the SQL query, so there should actually be no data from table 'hotel' at all in $row. Since I do not know your table structure, I can hardly tell which would be the correct JOIN.

Comment: I have two tables : 'hotel' and 'rates' . 
'hotel' table have following fields: hotel_id city_id country_id name photo1 photo2 photo3 photo4 photo5 hotel_address phone1 phone2 phone3 phone4 contact_email room_description area_description travel_description food_description rates_added 
and, 'rates' table have following fields::  
id hotel_id room_type default_price price_monday price_tuesday price_wednesday price_thursday price_friday price_saturday price_sunday

Comment: Erm, well, should be something like "SELECT * FROM hotel AS h INNER JOIN rates AS r ON r.hotel_id = h.hotel_id".

Comment: Thank you Dukeling, It works well. 
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this query

```
 Select h.*,r.default_price from hotel h left join rates r ON h.hotel_id=r.hotel_id

  or

 Select hotels.*,rates.default_price from hotel  left join rates  ON rates.hotel_id=hotel.hotel_id
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ebiztrait. Code already worked well from Dukeling, but your code also working well. Thanks again.